# Need help formatting the output of a variable into a list

Tags: c#, wpf

so I was provided a backend interface to gather some data from a call system and display it into a GUI that I'm building. I am new at this and using it as a learning project. I'm trying to filter some data into a list instead of one giant string. below is the code I'm using to display the data in the text block.

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        if (e.CmsData != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
                {
                    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
                    mylist.Add(item.AuxReasonDescription);

                }
                textBlock.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.CmsData.Agents); }));                   
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)       
}
```

as you can see in my `textBlock.Text` I was expecting to be able to put the variable `mylist` next to `Environment.NewLine`, but it wasn't able to find the variable.

Below is the .CS file where the list is being pulled from if it is needed to understand this.

Normally this would display a list of all logged in agents that is feeding from a interface that is not listed below. I'm trying to make this so each agent has a column containing data fields from the agent.cs file below. I may be going at this the complete wrong direction. any help that can be provided would be appreciated.

```
public class Agent : IEquatable<Agent>
{
    public int Extension { get; set; }
    public int WorkModeDirection { get; set; }
    public string WorkModeDirectionDescription { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AgTime { get; set; }
    public int AuxReason { get; set; }
    public string AuxReasonDescription { get; set; }
    public int DaInQueue { get; set; }
    public int WorkSkill { get; set; }
    public int OnHold { get; set; }
    public int Acd { get; set; }
    public String LoginId { get; set; }
    public string AgName { get; set; }
    public int EId { get; set; }
    public int Preference { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated { get; set; }
    public int CmId { get; set; }
    #region Implementation of IEquatable<Agent>

    public bool Equals(Agent other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return (other.LoginId == LoginId & other.CmId == CmId);
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Agent))
            return false;

        return Equals((Agent)obj);
    }

    //public override int GetHashCode()
    //{
    //    return LoginId;
    //}
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        string combinedNumber = "" + CmId + LoginId;
        int hash = Convert.ToInt32(combinedNumber);
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Agent left, Agent right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Agent left, Agent right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " Ag: [Ext:" + Extension + " login:" + LoginId + " AgName:" + AgName + " CmId:" + CmId + "]";
    }
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return LoginId != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: plus 1, you should atleast comment before voting down to whoever vote this question down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `myList` **inside** the `foreach` loop. Thatswhy the compiler doesn't know it anymore when you want to set the `textBlock.Text`. And what's worse: you thereby always create a **new list** for every iteration.

Simply move the declaration outside the `foreach`:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    mylist.Add(item.AuxReasonDescription);
}
textBlock.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList);
```

or using LINQ:

```
// no extra list and foreach needed
textBlock.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                             e.CmsData.Agents.Select(item => item.AuxReasonDescription));
```

(this only works if `e.CmsData.Agents` implements `IEnumerable<Agent>`. If it only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` you'll have to add `e.CmsData.Agents.OfType<Agent>.Select...`).

---

However, it *may* be better to build the string in the message handler (and on the thread that receives the message) than to do that on the UI thread:

```
if (e.CmsData != null)
{
    string text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                             e.CmsData.Agents.Select(item => item.AuxReasonDescription));
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
    {
        textBlock.Text = text;                   
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I actually stuck with my original format. glad it was an easy mistake that I just didn't catch. I seem to be making a lot of those recently. I wanted to use string.format to format this into columns of data instead of just dumping it.. Would you be able to assist with that easily or should I post a new question?

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 this sound rather like a new question, and I already left office (writing from my phone now), so I won't answer in the next 12 hours ;) glad I could help. If it solved _this_ question, you may mark this answer as accepted.